# how to have a variable number of parameters using `argparse` for nim

Tags: command-line-interface, nim-lang

I started today learning nim, so any kind of suggestion is welcome.

I tried using [argparse](https://www.iffycan.com/nim-argparse/argparse.html) thinking its similarity with Python's library would make my life easy.

I'd like to have an application with this interface:

```
tool [options] File1 File2 ... FileN
```

my parser object is like:

```
var p = newParser(prog):
  help("Dereplicate FASTA (and FASTQ) files, print dereplicated sorted by cluster size with ';size=NNN' decoration.")
  flag("-k", "--keep-name", help="Do not rename sequence, but use the first sequence name")
  flag("-i", "--ignore-size", help="Do not count 'size=INT;' annotations (they will be stripped in any case)")
  option("-m", "--min-size", help="Print clusters with size equal or bigger than INT sequences", default="0")
  option("-p", "--prefix", help = "Sequence name prefix", default = "seq")
  option("-s", "--separator", help = "Sequence name separator", default = ".")
  flag("-c", "--size-as-comment", help="Print cluster size as comment, not in sequence name")
  arg("inputfile", help="Input file")
```

I'm looking for something like `nargs="+"`, but from what I understand an integer is expected, and I didn't get how to specify an arbitrary number of inputs.

Thanks!

*PS*:

- The tool I'm using to experiment is [here](https://github.com/telatin/nim-stuff/tree/master/derep)

Comment: I also checked https://github.com/docopt/docopt.nim and it's a nice alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by adding `nargs=-1`:

```
import os
import argparse

proc main(args: seq[string]) =
  var par = newParser("My Program"):
    option("--arg1")
    arg("files", nargs = -1)

  var opts = par.parse(args)
  echo "Opts: ", opts.arg1
  echo "Files: ", opts.files
  # For a command like `cmd --arg1=X file1 file2, echoes
  # Opts: X
  # Files: @[file1, file2]

when isMainModule:
  main(commandLineParams())
```

If you want, say at least one FASTA, but many more possible, this is the syntax:

```
var par = newParser("My Program"):
  option("--arg1")
  arg("firstFile")
  arg("otherFiles", nargs = -1)
```

Now `par.firstFile` contains a string with the first file, and `par.otherFiles` contains a `seq[string]` with the rest of them.

---

Remember that Nim has its own [command line parser](https://nim-lang.org/docs/parseopt.html), that seems a bit complex at first, but for simple things it may be useful:

```
import os
import parseopt

proc main(args: seq[string]) =
  var par = initOptParser(args)
  var files: seq[string]

  for kind, key, val in args.getopt():
    case kind
    of cmdLongOption, cmdShortOption:
      # Here you deal with options like --option and -o
      discard
    of cmdArgument:
      # Here, any extra argument is added to the seq
      files.add key
    of cmdEnd: assert(false)

  echo files

when isMainModule:
  main(commandLineParams())
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been immensely useful. I tried messing with "nargs = -1" before but i was using a `proc main() =` declaration. Not sure if that alone was the problem but your script solved.

I'm also grateful for the alternative of using parseopt!

Comment: I can't say. `nargs` is the number of arguments to catch in the variable (here `opts.files`), by default 1. But -1 means "catch all remaining args".